# Kendo UI Button - on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm trying to find a way to set the click event for the kendo button.
The default action is to refresh page which I want to get rid of.

I want to close the current window when the button is pressed.
I'm working on ASP.NET MVC and using html helper to add the button.

```
        @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                .Name("closeFormBtn")
                .Content("Close")
                .Events(events => events
                    .Click("closeForm"))
        )
```

Unfortunately the above click event doesn't work and the default refresh action is applied every time a button is pressed.
The closeForm script works ok as it has already been tested.
I'm also trying to find a way of not using script at all, just to insert code inside the Click(" ") event.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. Would you mind posting the "closeForm" function and could you make sure it is declared globally? To write your function directly in the helper, you can simply write an anonymous function like so: .Click("function(e){ DoStuff(); }")

Comment: This seems to be working fine, however the problem with page being reloaded still exists. I would have thought adding click event would override the default action, but it didn't.

Comment: Then we don't have enough code to see your problem. There's something else that is wrong. Can you post the generated html/javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **should** work.

```
function closeForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //if that doesn't work, try adding:
    e.stopPropogation();

    //your code

}
```

Comment: I wish it had worked, but it didn't. I've tried both options with the same result - page reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

In the closeForm Method. Return false in the end of the function.

```
function closeForm(){

   //Your Code
   return false;

}
```

Comment: I don't think this should be required, but definitely worth a try since it's a standard javascript behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. When I press the button it still reloads the whole page.

Comment: Can you post the closeForm function ?